# Why this Error CS1061 appear when i want to build my game?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

the game can be played just fine, but when buid to apk but theres error

Assets/Source/LuaWrap/AnimatorOverrideControllerWrap.cs(214,21): error CS1061: Type `UnityEngine.AnimatorOverrideController' does not contain a definition for`PerformOverrideClipListCleanup' and no extension method `PerformOverrideClipListCleanup' of type`UnityEngine.AnimatorOverrideController' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I already looking on the web for solutions, but still can't find the exact solution

```
[MonoPInvokeCallbackAttribute(typeof(LuaCSFunction))]
static int PerformOverrideClipListCleanup(IntPtr L)
{
    LuaScriptMgr.CheckArgsCount(L, 1);
    AnimatorOverrideController obj = LuaScriptMgr.GetUnityObject<AnimatorOverrideController>(L, 1);
    obj.PerformOverrideClipListCleanup();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Error message seem to be correct - according to https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AnimatorOverrideController.html that class has no such method. Very unclear what you expect to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [`AnimatorOverrideController` source code](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/master/Modules/Animation/ScriptBindings/AnimatorOverrideController.bindings.cs)

```
[NativeConditional("UNITY_EDITOR")]
extern internal void PerformOverrideClipListCleanup();
```

you can see that it only exists in `UNITY_EDITOR` so within the Unity Editor itself and will not be built into any build app.

---

You can not use it in any build and should exclude your method and anything calling it using [`#if` Pre-Processors](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-if)

```
#if UNITY_EDITOR       
    [MonoPInvokeCallbackAttribute(typeof(LuaCSFunction))]
    static int PerformOverrideClipListCleanup(IntPtr L)
    {
        LuaScriptMgr.CheckArgsCount(L, 1);
        AnimatorOverrideController obj = LuaScriptMgr.GetUnityObject<AnimatorOverrideController>(L, 1);
        obj.PerformOverrideClipListCleanup();
        return 0;
    }
#endif
```

so this code block will be stripped of in a build the same way.